# Time estimate for reaching 155F for baking 9lb Turkey breast?

Tags: temperature, turkey

I have a 9lb turkey breast to bake. I've learned that I want the internal temp to register between 155-165 on an instant-read thermometer inserted into the deepest part of the breast when it's done.   Anyone know approximately how long that might take and what the best temp is? I've read about people baking turkey breast anywhere from 325F to 425F and can only imagine that much variability in baking temp would certainly affect the cooking time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

325 will take 3-4 hours and please wait until it reaches 160 in the center of the thickest part of the meat before taking it out.  Let it rest for 20-30 under tin foil before cutting.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Dave.  Anything that is roasted is better low and slow.  Gives flavors time to penetrate and tends to keep things moist.